# How to create a fancy badge (award graphics) in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Is it possible to create fancy badges in LaTeX? Are there any packages for this?

Below are some examples:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't ask "How do I achieve this layout", but rather a question about a specific feature that you're struggling with, one problem per question. This way other users who have a similar problem can benefit from your question and the solutions to it (No one's gonna ask for the same layout as you). It's no problem to ask several questions, if you've made some attempt yourself first. It's enormously helpful to see what you've tried so far to figure out what doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll then open myself to any designs and update the question accordingly. And I'll delete the background image not to restrict answers to this design.

Comment: I couldn't resize the images in my question. Any help with the syntax is welcome.

Comment: @doncherry Oh, thanks. I didn't know just plain HTML worked :S

Comment: Some does: http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#html / [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777)